# How to display pytest warnings in the generated HTML report?

Tags: pytest, pytest-html

I'm using **pytest** and **pytest-html** to generate reports. Having just found out about [warnings](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html), I'd like to have the warnings that I generate in tests with

```
warnings.warn(UserWarning(f'Whoops!'))
```

be shown somewhere in the generated HTML test report. At the moment, they're just shown in the console and I can't see an obvious way to achieve this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: It seems is a reported [issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2717) and happens with other type of reports. I've tried `--junitxml`, `--html-report` and `--html` and didn't work.